# Update cell value based on result from 2 other cells value

Tags: php, mysql, join

So I have a table looking like this:

table1

```
id   name    dad    mom    color
1    bob     12      4      NULL
4   embla    NULL   NULL    blue
12  clyde    NULL   NULL    blue
2   anna     12     4      NULL
```

I would like to SET anna & bobs color based on their parents color. It might not alway be blue..

I'm not very good at this but i've tried to alter another code I used for something else but that didn't work.

```
   UPDATE table1 AS p 
   INNER JOIN table1 AS Dad
      ON p.dad_id = dad.id AND p.mom_id = mom.id
         IF color = blue
SET p.color = blue
     .....?
```

This is how far I get and whereI struggle... As I dont know how to check for the parents color and then return the same color to the offspring.

So I want to set the same color as their parents in the color column, and if the parents color do not match I would like it to be NULL.

I don't have many colors to choose from so I can use the value "blue" in the code. I don't need to actually "match" the color value, I can use the value blue, red or yellow and run the script 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 p
JOIN table1 dad ON dad.id = p.dad_id AND dad.color = 'blue'
JOIN table1 mom ON mom.id = p.mom_id AND mom.color = 'blue'
SET p.color = 'blue';
```